# Minimality of a set and its equivalent statement

Tags: general-topology, analysis, dynamical-systems

If $X$ is compact and $f: X \to X$ be a homeomorphism; We call $\Lambda \subseteq X$ minimal if it is non-empty, compact and $f$-invariant($f(\Lambda)=\Lambda$) but no proper subset of $\Lambda$ is non-empty compact invariant.

According to Lan Wen's differentiable Dynamics book, the minimality of a set is equivalent to this fact :

> $\Lambda \subseteq X$ is minimal if and only if the orbit of every $x \in \Lambda$ is dense in $
> \Lambda$. ($\overline{O(x)}=\Lambda$).Notice that this theorem holds if we replaced "Obit" with "Positive" or "Negative" Orbit.

Now I wanna try to prove this:

Suppose $\Lambda \subseteq X$ is a compact invariant set.
$\Lambda$ is minimal if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $N\geq 0$ such that for every $x \in \Lambda$, every point $y \in \Lambda$ is in the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of the set $\{f^n(x)\}_{n=-N}^N$

I almost proved this but there is something which confuses me:

Proof:

Since $\Lambda$ is minimal so the orbit of evety $x\in \Lambda$ is dense in $\Lambda$:
\begin{align}
\forall  x \in \Lambda \quad\overline{O(x)}=\Lambda
\end{align}
So if $y \in \Lambda$ is arbitrary for every nbd of $y$ such as $U_y$ we have :
\begin{align}
U_y \cap O(x) \neq \emptyset
\end{align}
So there is $w \in \Lambda$ which also belongs to $O(x)$ so there is $N\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $w=f^N(x)$. Since $U_y$ was an arbitrary nbd of $y$ so for every $\varepsilon>0$ we have $d(y,w)<\varepsilon$ so $d(y,f^N(x))<\varepsilon$.

But this is just for specific $N$ how could I prove this for $-N, \cdots, N-1$?

Is it good to use the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\Lambda$ ?

Comment: For each $y\in \Lambda$ take $N_y$ with $d(y,f^{N_y}(x))<\varepsilon.$ The family $\{B_d(y, \varepsilon):y\in\Lambda\}$ of open balls is an open cover of $\Lambda$ and $\Lambda$ is assumed to be compact so..............?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Tnx.. Every open cover of $\Lambda$ has a finite subcover ... I was ignoring this, but Does this guarantee that this family change from $-N ,\cdots, N$ ?

Comment: Let $F$ be a finite subset of $\Lambda$ such that $\{B_d(y,\varepsilon):y\in F\}$ covers $\Lambda.$.  Let $N=\max \{N_y:y\in F\}.$